# How can we take a backup of the application data from the Google App Engine DataStore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I read about the DataStore admin, but can't find it in the console. Also, the doc says the feature is experimental?

More clarification:
We have an enterprise application, and we need to be able to take backups of our data at a certain frequency. Since we are using Google App Engine, we need to be able to take a backup off the App Engine DataStore. When I go into the Admin console, I can see the option to view the entities, I see "Dashboard","Query" and "Index" but nothing to take a backup of the DataStore data, say to something like CloudStorage. Also, when I go to localhost:8000/datastore, I see the same.

Comment: mind giving more context or details? When I go to localhost:8080 (or my app, if I uploaded it)/_ah/admin, and then go to my "datastore viewer" I have all the functionalities described in the docs...

Comment: Sure, so we have an enterprise application, and we need to be able to take backups of our data at a certain frequency. Since we are using Google App Engine, we need to be able to take a backup off the App Engine DataStore.
When I go into the Admin console, I can see the option to view the entities, I see "Dashboard","Query" and "Index" but nothing to take a backup of the DataStore data, say to something like CloudStorage.
Also, when I go to localhost:8000/datastore, I see the same. _ah/admin gave me a 404 error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Datastore Admin is only available to Python applications - or rather, applications with a Python version.  If your app is Java, you can deploy an empty/trivial app to a non-default version.

There's a note on this in the docs, [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#a_note_for_java_developers).

Answer (score 0):

At the time of your request it was only available in the old GAE console.
Since few weeks it has been integrated in the new console as well.
Go to Storage/Cloud Datastore/Settings, then the first time you'll have to "Enable Datastore Admin", then you'll have a new button "Open Datastore Admin"